# Adding a second datepicker,

Tags: php, jquery, html, datepicker

I need some help with this datepickerthat i'll be using in my school project.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" name='cout' id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

I want to create another datepicker since my project is a hotel reservation. Check in and Check out dates. But in check out this happens.

[image: 2nd Datepicker]

Comment: show the code of the 2nd datepicker

Comment: that is the same code. I tried changing the name and the id of the 2nd datepicker but didn't work

Comment: so u run the function twice too? it would be much better for other ppl to help you if you show your code. They might see issues that your nto able to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<p>Date1: <input type="text"  id="datepicker1"></p>
<p>Date2: <input type="text"  id="datepicker2"></p>
 <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker1,#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `class` instead of an `id` to define the date inputs :

i.e. :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" name='cout' class="datepicker" id="start_date"></p>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" name='cout' class="datepicker" id="end_date"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Adrien Leber that a class could be easier once you have multiple datepickers. I think you need to use `.each()` though.

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").each(function(i, val) {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```